# Why sorting using CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions is slow?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, icollectionview

This is the default sort method when you click on a column header in a `DataGrid`. When the underlying list contains 100,000 items, it takes about 20 seconds to refresh the view. Same delay can be observed when setting `SortDescription`s on a `CollectionView`.

Sorting by using `ListCollectionView.CustomSort` or by sorting and re-assinging the list works almost instantly.

Why is this delay? Is this just a "reflection tax" on the bound properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are right, this is a reflection tax. I looked very closely on DataGrid performance some time ago, and reflection was a bottle neck here. No matter how fast is sorting algorithm, they don't cache property's value between two comparisons. So, even if you have n*ln(n) comparisons, with n == 100 000  you'll get ~1 000 000 operations. Each operand uses reflection to get value, so you have 2 000 000 calls to reflection in tax :) ... `ListCollectionView.CustomSort` is ideal solution here.

PS: At the end of the day, we wrote ListView-based grid, because we were not satisfied with DataGrid rendering performance too... But that's another story :)

Comment: Does this work with live sorting? (ListCollectionView.LiveSortingProperties)

Answer (score 1):

The best performance tweak for filtering, was toggling DataGridRow Visibility. It made magnitude of difference!

1.Add IsVisible property to the Collection Item that you Bind the DataGrid's ItemSource to.

```
private bool _isVisible = true;
public bool IsVisible
{
    get { return _isVisible; }
    set 
    { 
        if (_isVisible == value)
             return;
        _isVisible = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=>IsVisible);
     }
 }
```

2.Trigger the Visibility of DataGridRow by binding it to your IsVisible property:

```
<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                Value="{Binding Path=IsVisible, 
                                Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"/>
 </Style>
</DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
```

3.Well, you gotta set the IsVisible somewhere I guess too, like in your ViewModel. Here's just a sample of what I am doing (just copy/paste job) - basically setting IsVisible to true or false based on some criteria in my other ViewModel:

```
FilterViewModel.OnFilter += (s, a) =>
{
    foreach (Row row in ViewModel.Rows)
    row.IsVisible = !FilterViewModel.FilteringItems.Any(item => 
                                   item.IsSelected && item.Name == row.Name);
};
```

Comment: This worked for me. This is how a similar problem can be solved in Angular by the way :).